# How to create Customtom Authorize Attribute in .net core web api 3.1?

Tags: c#, api, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, custom-authentication

I have two api project

1. **ConsumerApi**
2. **MasterApi**

**MasterApi** is responsible for creating and validating a token. I need to protect **ConsumerApi** resources. That's why I have a **LoginController** with **login** method.

At first  **User** hit this method and pass their UserName and Password. **ConsumerApi** then call **MasterApi** for a token and return the token to **User**. After then **User** use this JWT token in **Authorization** header as  **Bearer retrive_jwt_token** to call **ConsumerApi** protected resources. To validate the token with **MasterApi** I have a **CustomAuthorizeAttribute** in **ConsumerApi** which I mention above this project  Controllers or Methods.

Below is my **CustomAuthorizeAttribute** :

```
public class ExternalAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        public ExternalAuthorization()
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var authHeader))
            {
                var accessToken = authHeader.ToString().Split(' ')[1];
                var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(
                    $"https://localhost:44359/api/oauth/validate?token={accessToken}").Result;
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I use this in one of my **ConsumerApi** controller method like below:

```
        [ExternalAuthorization]
        [HttpGet("getall")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetAll()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

But when I call this method I'm getting below exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint ConsumerApiClient.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.GetAll (ConsumerApi) contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization.
Configure your application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() inside the call to Configure(..) in the application startup code. The call to app.UseAuthorization() must appear between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.ThrowMissingAuthMiddlewareException(Endpoint endpoint)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.7
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6InVzZXJfaWQiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJyZWd1bGFyIiwibmJmIjoxNTk0MTE1MDg4LCJleHAiOjE1OTQyMDE0ODgsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0MzU5LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0MzU5LyJ9.mOEaM_IuQ0w_CKGcMHXACXCdCOebzdc19ArSeOOgxek
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Host: localhost:44326
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
dnt: 1
x-postman-interceptor-id: 9dc8740c-6d4d-eb6b-4376-3eefdb355cb8
postman-token: 3191c452-708a-efd0-237a-0c343eb16bd6
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Do I need to add this in **StartUp.cs** if so then how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception, `app.UseAuthorization` should be between `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseEndpoints(...)`, something like this:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Yeah I also add those But still got the error, It says Authentication Schema not found